# Two view controllers have the same storyboard identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

As the title suggests I am getting the error that two view controllers have the same identifier but the problem is, they don't! I have checked through all my storyboards multiple times and never saw any with the identifier! The full error is

> Two view controllers have the same storyboard identifier "IAC".

Not only that, but there are no storyboards with the identifier "IAC". Its possible I may have named one that a long time ago but their certainly aren't any now. I also just updated Xcode to the ios 7.1 SDK and it's possible that's part of the error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Clean.  Restart Xcode.  And keep in mind, this means the view controllers have the same names... not the storyboards.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode's cache can be out of date. Try saving your project, closing Xcode, reopening project, and then rebuilding.

Comment: I have solved this issue here
........

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594913/two-view-controllers-have-the-same-storyboard-identifier/24305981#24305981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove derive data from Xcode -> Prefrences -> Locations -> DerivedData and rerun the project

Comment: Should I just delete the folder? Or the contents of it?

Comment: @user2547771 you should look again there should be another view controller with same identifier.Look in `Storyboard Id` of all view controllers.

Answer (score 11):

In that case, press `Command + Shift + F` and then type the identifier that is being mentioned in the Warning / Error area.

Here after you search there will be list of matches, in that select Storyboard icons, and your answer lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried cleaning your project temp and caches files and restarting Xcode? Sometimes this simple step can solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my application. I could not find any information regarding this in web.
I have cleaned and deleted derived data nothing could not help me.

After some time I found solution for this.

I have assigned one story board identifier to two view controllers in scene(where we can see entire views at one place) in my application.  After some time I realised this error and solved it.

goto->storyboard scene->click on view controllers and observe the identity inspector in the  control panel.

if you assigned the same story board identifier to 2 or more view controllers then remove it.
Delete viewController name which is assigned for 2 or more view controllers in the Identity inspector. I hope I am able to make everyone understand.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, press Command + Shift + F and then search by type the identifier that (exam problem search by name "IAC") 
you will see duplicate data after you see that you choose delete and build again.